# Octomap and Projected Octomap not lining up

Tags: ros, octomap

I am trying to use a projected Octomap as an occupancy grid to pass onto the ROS navigation stack, but when I create one using the octomap_server package, it creates an occupancy grid which is rotated 90 degrees from the top down view (i.e., It projects from the side when it should be projecting downwards). The Octomap and the projected Octomap are shown below.
[image]
[image]

Is there any way to change the direction from which Octomap creates the projection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can use dynamic configure to modify the parameters dynamically and check if fix your orientation
[Octomap Params](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/kinetic-devel/octomap_server/cfg/OctomapServer.cfg)

```
rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure
```

Or add in your launch file a static transform Publisher between your robot base_link and map frames with desired orientation

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="octomap_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 map base_link 100" />
```

Comment: The second suggestion solved my issue, thank you!

Comment: Glad you reached! Congratulations 